# Why does the dotnet watch publish command not work after update?

Tags: .net, dotnet-cli

When I run dotnet watch publish it appears to be ignoring the publish command and trying to do run instead.

This is the error:

```
PS D:\Development\ProjectOne> dotnet watch publish --project Client/ --configuration Release
dotnet watch  Started
Unable to run your project.
Ensure you have a runnable project type and ensure 'dotnet run' supports this project.
A runnable project should target a runnable TFM (for instance, net5.0) and have OutputType 'Exe'.
The current OutputType is 'Library'.
dotnet watch ❌ Exited with error code 1
dotnet watch ⏳ Waiting for a file to change before restarting dotnet...
```

I tried running with and without the publish command and same result also tried with different configurations but no dice.

Answer (score 0):

Add a global.json file to the directory where commands are being executed, specifying the desired .NET SDK version.

```json
    {
      "sdk": {
        "version": "7.0.0",
        "rollForward": "minor",
        "allowPrerelease": false
      }
    }
```

references: [dotnet watch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-watch), [dotnet publish](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-publish), [dotnet run](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-run), [Select the .NET version to use](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/versions/selection), [global.json overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/global-json)

---

I ran this command with the *verbose* option.

`dotnet watch --verbose --project test_project.csproj publish --configuration Release`

```
Running dotnet with the following arguments: 'run publish --configuration Release'
```

A known issue where dotnet watch prefixes the input command with run.

Found several reports of this issue on Github: [dotnet watch broken in 8.0.100](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/36918), [dotnet-watch support for publish subprocess](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/38340)